# javac no source files found

Tags: java

I have the `.java` file on the current working directory but javac reports:

```
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I'm working on ubuntu.

Comment: did you try javac <case-sensitive-filename>.java ?

Comment: Please show us what commands you're trying.

Comment: i used tab so that the terminal would fill the rest of the filename.

Comment: Once again, please show us what you're trying.

Comment: javac -cp .;lib.jar a.java works on windows. But it doesnot work on ubuntu  when i change it to javac -cp lib.jar a.java it works on ubuntu. Is the classpath seperator platform dependent ?

Comment: @user: Yes, it is platform dependent.

Comment: @userNNNNN Try calling System.getProperty("path.separator").  Alternatively visit this URL (http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=path.separator) from browsers on both systems.  And as an aside, please exchange your 'prison number' for a nic or name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From your comment above, it looks like you tried:

`javac -cp .;lib.jar a.java` on your Ubuntu system.  The `CLASSPATH` separator is `:` on Unix systems and `;` on Windows.

Ubuntu considered the command up to the `;`, `java -cp .` and thus gave the message.

`javac -cp .:lib.jar a.java` should compile fine.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is using powersehll on windows use CLASSPATH separator `:`  instead of `;`

Comment: You got it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a similar thing and found that you need to mention the absolute path when you are using the 
-cp and -d option with javac like this

javac -cp 'ur location of jars & files'; -d 'location to add your classes to'   'absolute path of file'

eg:

javac -cp C:\home\lib\mywork; -d c:\home\classes  c:\home\files*.java

Comment: this worked for me, adding the full path on mac. previously it was working with relative path... anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for javac, there are options and arguments
arg: it takes argument as path of source file
options: we require for basic compilation

-sourcepath: the path of dependent source files
-d: directory path of output classes

```bash
javac -sourcepath './src' -d './bin' -verbose './src/App.java'
```

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD in your directory that has source code, then type the following command:

```
javac -d . SourceFileName.java
```

then Enter and after that ....

run the class file using..

```
java packageName.SourceFileName
```

Hope this helps, most probably you missed the . after `-d`