# Trouble with shell script that calls javac

Tags: java, bash, shell

Hello I'm completely new to Linux and shell scripts. I am trying to make a program which compiles and runs a Java program.

```
#!/bin/bash
javac Test.java
javac testObject.java
java Test
```

When I try to run it I get `javac: no source files`. I also tried putting the full class path for it.

Comment: Make sure that the files are in the same folder as the script's current directory. Also, classes should start with an Upper case character.

Comment: Try to execute command "javac Test.java" from Terminal at first.

Comment: I've been compiling and running it in terminal before and it's been working, and the script is in the same folder as the classes.

Comment: What matters is not where the script is. What matters is the directory from which it's executed: the one which is printed by the `pwd` command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javac no source files found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012125/javac-no-source-files-found)

Answer (score 0):

Add some variables and checks in your bash script like this. This will help avoid simple mistakes. Also note that I changed the class name testObject.java to TestObject.java ->

```
#!/bin/bash
project_dir="/$HOME/myprojects/Test" 
cd $project_dir
echo "Compiling Test project.."
if [ javac -cp . Test.java ] && [ javac -cp . TestObject.java ];
then
   echo "Compilation successful! Running project Test"
   java Test
else
   echo "Compilation failed. Cannot run Test project"
fi
```

You can make script more elegant as per your need. Read more about javac command-line here -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

I am not sure why you are compiling TestObject.java separately. But if it is being referred in Test.java and hence you are doing so then its unnecessary. All subsequent referred java classes will be compiled automatically along with Test.java if they are being used in Test.java.