# How can I import Java .JAR files into INTELLIJ community version

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am a new programmer with very little previous experience of Java (last program I studied was Fortran). 
I am using a MAC PRO. I have downloaded and installed **Intellij Idea** (community version), and written a few programs, and am trying to install the **`.jar`** file from a tutorial. 
I have tried to follow the instructions using the terminal, but with no luck. 
Here is the first line of my  terminal code to run the `.jar` file:

```
java -classpath .:/c:/Downloads/GridWorldCode/gridworld.jar
```

and I get the following message:

> javac: no source files Usage: javac   use -help
>    for a list of possible options.

I have tried with and without the `"c:"` and with and without the `"/"` preceding the `"c:"`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are planning to run your code from IntelliJ, there is a fairly straightforward way to add a JAR dependency to your project.

Comment: And if you are trying to run `java` or `javac` from the command line with a JAR file on the classpath, there are straight-forward ways to do that as well.

Comment: take reference from a book like https://github.com/arpitjindal97/technology_books/blob/master/Java/head-first-java-2nd-edition.zip

Comment: But if you are using a Mac, why on earth are you trying to use pathnames with what looks like a Windows drive name ("C:")?

Comment: The answer already have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012125/javac-no-source-files-found